# Qual a diferença entre IEnumerable<T> e IEnumerable?

Tags: c#

Tentei ver o código de ambas interfaces, mas a única diferença que vejo que é o `IEnumerable<T>` tem o método `IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();`, e que na interface `IEnumerator<T>` o `Current` retorna o "T" ao invés de um object...
Isso seria apenas para evitar que o foreach faça um unboxing depois? ou não?
E outra dúvida, normalmente se faz outra classe mesmo para implementar a interface `IEnumerator` e implementa todos os métodos MoveNext, Reset, Current, etc... ou só implementar o `IEnumerable<T>` e retornar um GetEnumerator() da Lista já basta?
Exemplo:

```
public IEnumerator<Error> GetEnumerator()
{
    return this._errors.GetEnumerator();
}

IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return this._errors.GetEnumerator();
}
```

`GetEnumerator()` é um método da Classe Array que retorna para nós uma class que implementa o `IEnumerator<T>` mesmo?

Comment: O padrao e' implementar o segundo metodo assim: `return GetEnumerator();` de modo a evitar a duplicacao de codigo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Qual a diferença entre `IEnumerable<T>` e `IEnumerable`?

Em teoria não deveria existir essa distinção. O problema é que no .NET 1.0 foi implementado primeiro `IEnumerable`. Os tipo genéricos só vieram a partir do .NET 2.0.

Sem delongas, `IEnumerable` basicamente devolve iteradores do tipo `Object`, e `IEnumerable<T>` devolve iteradores tipados.

> ...na interface `IEnumerator<T>` o `Current` retorna o "T" ao invés de
>   um `object`... Isso seria apenas para evitar que o foreach faça um
>   unboxing depois? ou não?

Não, na verdade a distinção é pura e simplesmente por segurança de tipos. Conversões que poderiam surgir no meio do caminho poderiam causar problemas caso o programador tentasse conversões usando tipos diferentes.

> E outra dúvida, normalmente se faz outra classe mesmo para implementar
>   a interface `IEnumerator` e implementa todos os métodos `MoveNext`,
>   `Reset`, `Current`, etc... ou só implementar o `IEnumerable<T>` e
>   retornar um `GetEnumerator()` da Lista já basta?

Se você só implementar os dois `GetEnumerator()` já funciona. A implementação método a método é necessária caso você queira um comportamento diferente do padrão da implementação conhecida.

Comment: Ah! Outra coisa que esqueci de perguntar, pq IEnumerator<T> implementa IDisposable mas IEnumerator não? Seria apenas para liberar espaço que o IEnumerator cria no foreach( no caso, a Lista/Vetor/Matriz que ele cria ) ?

Comment: Pelo mesmo motivo de existir dois tipos. A questão é que é um pouco diferente, na verdade. O `foreach` nunca conferia se o tipo em questão implementava `IDisposable` até a versão 1.2. Só depois disso é que passou a ter a chamada a `IDisposable` após o `foreach`.

Comment: "Não, na verdade a distinção é pura e simplesmente por segurança de tipos." - Nao e' completamente verdade. Genericos foram introduzidos nao' so para fortalecer o *type system*, mas tambem para evitar boxing e melhorar a performance.